# How to refactor 2 implementations of interface that vary slightly

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I have 2 classes that implement an interface. As you can see the implementation of interface method Evaluate is very similar in both the classes but varies sliggly. How to factor out the duplicate code here

```
public class Policy1 : IPolicy
{
    private readonly IPolicy _innerPolicy1;
    private readonly IPolicy _innerPolicy2;

    public Task Evaluate(Input input)
    {
        _innerPolicy1.Evaluate(input);
        _innerPolicy2.Evaluate(input);

        return Task.FromResult(input);
    }
}

public class Policy2 : IPolicy
{
    private readonly IPolicy _innerPolicy1;
    private readonly IPolicy _innerPolicy2;
    private readonly IPermissionService _permissionService;

    public Task Evaluate(Input input)
    {
        _innerPolicy1.Evaluate(input);
        if (HasInnerPolicy2Permission(input))
        {
            _innerPolicy2.Evaluate(input);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(input);
    }

    private bool HasInnerPolicy2Permission(Input input)
    {
        return _permissionService.GetInnerPolicy2Permission(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably better asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: And your answer is basically "via an abstract class that inherits from `IPolicy` ", because it looks like functionality differs enough you can't just cram the two classes together as they are.

Comment: Far more concerning that the repetition of two very very simple lines of code called at different places under different circumstances is the fact that these methods purport to be asynchronous, and yet do all of their work synchronously.

Comment: If the two classes contain same functionality and change in one or two places. 
I would recommend the template method pattern.
See [here](http://www.dofactory.com/net/template-method-design-pattern) and [here](https://exceptionnotfound.net/the-daily-design-pattern-template-method/).

Comment: It's also one of those questions where the real names of the policies would help. The repetition might be accidental, or it might be related to repetition (relations) in the problem domain. Of course, you can always refactor out the repeating code, but you might not be making a good design (especially if it's accidental repetition).

Answer (score 1):

Derive Policy1 & Policy2 from an abstract class the implements Evaluate as per your Policy2 class & has an abstract method for HasInnerPolicy2Permission - Policy1 simply returns true, Policy2 implements as in that class.

Something like :

```
public abstract class Policy : IPolicy
{
    protected readonly IPolicy _innerPolicy1;
    protected readonly IPolicy _innerPolicy2;

   public Task Evaluate(Input input)
    {
        _innerPolicy1.Evaluate(input);
        if (HasInnerPolicy2Permission(input))
        {
            _innerPolicy2.Evaluate(input);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(input);
    }

    protected abstract bool HasInnerPolicy2Permission(Input input);
}

public class Policy1 : Policy
{
    protected override bool HasInnerPolicy2Permission(Input input)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public class Policy2 : Policy
{
    private readonly IPermissionService _permissionService;
    protected override bool HasInnerPolicy2Permission(Input input)
    {
        return _permissionService.GetInnerPolicy2Permission(input);
    }
}
```

If you thought you may have a Policy3 class with significantly different Evaluate function, then you could make the original version virtual.